# Accessing Android crash reports

Tags: android, logging, crash, google-play, feedback

I was just using Sports Tracker when it crashed, and when I pressed "Report" button to report the crash, I'm given a simple input field asking for a comment regarding the crash.

However, pressing "preview" will give me insight of what data is being send with the crash log. The amount of data is actually immense, including date/time, device name/version, system log, stack trace etc. All kinds of usable data.

From logcat I can see that this is `com.google.android.feedback` activity.

**The question** is, is this something Sports Tracker developers implemented themselves, or is it the default crash report every android user has installed on their phones? In other words, do all my apps (=the ones I've written and posted to Play Store) already have this function, or is it something I could/should implement myself**?

I have received some crash reports via android's build in crash reporting service, but it doesn't really give me any useful data (besides stack trace). Or is it just that the crash reporting on developer's dashboard is still far from complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about this special feedback activity. I'm currently using the ACRA system that it's really easy to use and give me useful bug reports. Let's have a look on it for your bug report.

Answer (score 1):

I am sure they must be using one of these.

ACRA is great as well as try ZUbhium, it comes with silent crash reporting & in app support desk. So whenever application crashes, it captures more meaningful data and does analysis onit  .

You can either add Zubhium as backend to ACRA & view advanced crash reports or use ZubhiumSDK. Both do excellent job.

Answer (score 0):

Actually TestPoke is a beta testing platform that allow you to see all crashes your android app fall in, even thought they notify you when such thing happens through it Android App.

http://www.testpoke.com